# Timescale D3js from 23 to 11

Tags: d3.js

I want to make my timescale from 23:00 to 7:00.

My data:

```
date        close
23:03:34    2 
23:06:34    3 
23:15:34    9 
23:57:34    42 
00:08:12    8 
01:08:12    60 
02:08:12    60 
03:08:12    60 
04:08:12    60 
04:08:12    0 
05:08:12    60 
05:13:24    5 
06:28:24    9
```

Now it makes from 00-23!

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code:

```
 var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
 width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%H:%M:%S").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
.range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(x)
.orient("bottom")
.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%H:%M"));

 var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(y)
.orient("left");


var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

 var svg = d3.select("#graph").append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");



function make_x_axis() {        
  return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
     .orient("bottom")
     .ticks(5)
 }

  function make_y_axis() {        
return d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(20)
  }

 d3.tsv("datafordiagramm_masch2_fruh.asp", function(error, data) {
 data.forEach(function(d) {
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
d.close = +d.close;
});

 x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
 y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));



  svg.append("g")         
  .attr("class", "grid")
  .call(make_y_axis()
  .tickSize(-width, 0, 0)
  .tickFormat("")
   .tickValues([5])
   )

  svg.append("g")         
    .attr("class", "grid")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(make_x_axis()
        .tickSize(-height, 0, 0)
        .tickFormat("")

    )



  svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

 svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Zeit in Minuten");

  svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
   });
```

now there are two lines, they start from coordinate 0/0. but i want one line from 23:00(pm) to 7:00 (am)

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: You might need the timezone offset: %Z - time zone offset, such as "-0700". See" https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting